# Ruby: the role of `initialize`

Tags: ruby, oop, object

I'm wondering if there's a convention / best practice for how `initialize` should be used when building Ruby classes. I've recently built a class as follows:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(file_path)
    @mapped_file = map_file(file_path)
  end

  def map_file(file_path)
    # do some processing and return the data
  end

  def run
    @mapped_file.do_something
  end
end
```

This uses `initialize` to do a lot of heavy lifting, before methods are subsequently called (all of which rely on `@mapped_data`).

My question is whether such processing should be handled outside of the constructor, with `initialize` used simply to store the instances' inputs. Would the following, for example, be preferable?

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(file_path)
    @file_path = file_path
  end

  def run
    mapped_file.do_something_else do
      etc_etc
    end
  end

  def mapped_file(file_path)
    @mapped_file ||= map_the_file_here
  end
end
```

I hope this question isn't considered too opinion based, but will happily remove if it's deemed to be.

So, is there a 'correct' way to use `initialize`, and how would this fit with the scenarios above?

Any questions or comments, let me know.

Comment: The constructor must prepare the object to work. It should not do any work. What *"prepare"* and *"do"* means is different for each class. The constructor of a log class that puts the logged data into a file will open the file. Opening the file in the constructor might not be appropriate for another class that works with a file in a different way.

Comment: @axiac: this is what I was trying to convey. You should post this as an answer (maybe elaborate a little bit)

Comment: In OOP, the initializer should usually prepare an object invariant. That is set up some properties of an object which hold throughout its lifecycle, regardless of what methods are called on the object.

Comment: Cheers folks, much appreciated. It's where my thinking was, although I wanted to ensure I wasn't abusing the initializer in some unacceptable manner. Will happily accept an answer here - @axiac you've the most votes if you want to post one.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, constructor is usually used to prepare the object, not do any actual work. More than a ruby convention, this a rule of thumb of almost all Object-Oriented languages.

What does "preparing the object" usually entail? Initializing members with default values, assigning passed arguments, calling the initializer of a super-class if such exists, etc.

In your case, this how I would rewrite your class:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(file_path)
    @file_path = file_path
  end

  def map_file
    @mapped_file ||= map_file_here(@file_path)
  end

  def run
    map_file.do_something
  end
end
```

Since `run` requires the file to be mapped, it always calls `map_file` first. But the internal `map_file_here` executes only once.